# Average only for NonEmpty - SSAS MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, average

For one day (several datetime records possible) I want to create a 2nd measure computing an `AVG` only for `nonempty` values based on my 1st measure. I've tried the following :

```
"CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[M2] 
AS AVG([Measures].[M1]),
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'DATA' ;"
```

But the SSAS AVG function seems to return me a Sum:

DateTime        "M1"
1/1/16 12:10    "10"
1/1/16 13:10    "12"
1/1/16 14:10
1/1/16 15:10    "9"
1/1/16 16:10
1/1/16 17:10    "21"
1/1/16 18:10
1/1/16 19:10    "2"

Average for nonempty Measure values (10+12+9+21+2)/5 nonempty Values = 10,8

Comment: Is there a way to obtain the number of nonempty values for M1? in my date set example the expected answer is 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an average daily value then @whytheq showed a way to do it in MDX. But I believe you want a simple average. The proper way to do that in SSAS is to create a measure M1 tied to SQL column M1 with AggregateFunction=Sum (which you already have) and a second measure M1_Count on SQL column M1 in that measure group with an AggregateFunction=Count.

Then create a calculated measure:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[M1 Avg] as
IIF([Measures].[M1_Count]=0,null,[Measures].[M1]/[Measures].[M1_Count]);
```

Comment: Hello GregGAlloway, i tried this solution before my post but didn't reach the expected results. the AVG computed with a SUM(M1)/COUNT(Rows) takes into account empty values of M1 where i want to keep only Nonempty ones

Comment: @SESAMAREVA correct. That's why you need an M1_Count measure which is s count of that particular column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate your average *over a set* so you need to introduce a first argument to the `AVG` function.

From here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146067.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

This is the definition:

> Avg( Set_Expression [ , Numeric_Expression ] )

Instead of `AVG([Measures].[M1])` try this:

```
AVG(
 nonempty([Date].[Calendar].[Date], [Measures].[M1])
 ,[Measures].[M1]
)
```

...but I believe the AVG function will take care of nulls for you. So the following should be equivalent:

```
AVG(
  [Date].[Calendar].[Date]
 ,[Measures].[M1]
)
```

Comment: I submitted a different answer that I think is a better answer for this particular question.

Comment: @GregGalloway no worries at all: I'm not allowed to tinker with our cube set-up or design, so I was partly guessing the above.